# How do I import multiple DBs at the same time in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL DB server with 100s of DBs (all relatively small in size). I want to export all of them at once and them import them all at once via MySQL Workbench.

I'm able to fairly easily export all of the DBs at once by simply checking all the DBs I want to export and saving them all to one self-contained file.

However, when I try to import that saved file, it requires me to pick a single default schema to import to, which then imports the data for just that one schema, instead of all the backed up schemas.

What's the best way to import multiple DBs that are all lumped together into one SQL file in MySQL Workbench? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure this out.

When you export multiple DBs, if you check the **Include Create Schema** option, then you don't have to select a default schema when you import all the DBs, and it'll work fine.